Qt6 QWebEngine Plotly js: Uncaught Error: Something went wrong with axis scaling
I.m using Qt 6.6.3, VS 2022, python 311 to plot something like 3D image. When I create QWebEngineView object like
    ui.setupUi(this);

    webEnginePlot = new QWebEngineView(tabPlot);
    webEnginePlot->setObjectName("webEnginePlot");
    webEnginePlot->setUrl(QUrl(QString::fromUtf8("about:blank")));

MainWindow include
[ MenuBar                  ]
[QDockWidget QStackedWidget]
QDockWidget on the left, QStackedWidget on the right.
QDockWidget include QTreeView, QStackedWidget include QWebEngine
Question 1: Why the whole surface flashing(or hide, or white screen) 1 or 2 seconds?
I found out it is loading QtWebEngineProcessd.exe
When I try to new QWebEngineView() before QTreeView init, nothing wrong.
And when I init QTreeView first, then new QWebEngineView(), and the whole soft began to flashing(or hide, or white screen) to loading the QtWebEngineProcessd;
Question 2: I use C++ PythonAPI to draw a plot using plotly, and come out a file like a.html, and then I load the html file with QWebEngineView, and it showed up "js: Uncaught Error: Something went wrong with axis scaling"
    QUrl localUrl = QUrl::fromLocalFile(htmlFile);
    ui.webEnginePlot->setUrl(localUrl);
    ui.webEnginePlot->show();

But when I enter the QWidget and click my button to draw it again, and it works.
Why when initializing, it will report an error？
How to solve the problem.
Help me please!
